# TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined / Embeds

Tags: discord.js

When i'm doing a discord bot i have this problem client.commands.get('embed').execute(message, args, Discord);
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined
at Client. (C:\Users\anton\Desktop\Bot\index.js:29:37)
at Client.emit (node:events:376:20)
at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\anton\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\anton\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\anton\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\anton\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\anton\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\anton\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
at WebSocket.emit (node:events:376:20)
at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\anton\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:825:20)

This is the code :

````
const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = ',';

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
 
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
  client.user.setActivity('this awesome server', { type: 'WATCHING'}).catch(console.error);
});

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
 
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    
    if(command === 'embed'){
        client.commands.get('embed').execute(message, args, Discord);
    }

    if(command === 'version'){
        client.commands.get('version').execute(message, args);
    }
});

client.login('My token');```

And the command code:
module.exports = {
    name: 'version',
    description: "this is the version command",
    execute(message, args, Discord){
        const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
     .setColor('#e62e1e')
     .setTitle('Leon')
     .setDescription('Almost Finished')
     .addFields(
    { name: 'Regular field title', value: 'Some value here' },
    { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
    { name: 'Something', value: 'Nothing', inline: true },
    { name: 'Something', value: 'Nothing', inline: true },
     )
     .setTimestamp()
     .setFooter('See Leon');

    message.channel.send(exampleEmbed)
    }
}
````

Comment: What files do you have in your commands folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you didn't import *discord.js*.
This is how to do it: place this at the very top:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
```